# jQuery validation not work in Ajax Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I submit my form using jQuery `$.post` method and need to validation form using jQuery validation plugin  like this :

HTML :

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="send.php">User:
    <input type="text" value="" name="user" />
    <br/>Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="xyz" value="123" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true" />
    <?php $token=N oCSRF::generate( 'csrf_token' );?>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
</form>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="ajax-form-1">Run Code</button>
<div id="ajax-form-msg1"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#myform').validate({

    rules: {
        user: {
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $("#ajax-form-1").click(function () {
            $("#ajax-form-msg1").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");

            //  var formData = $("#myform").serialize();  //or
            var formData = $("#myform").serializeArray();

            var URL = $("#myform").attr('action');
            $.post(URL,
            formData,

            function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#ajax-form-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">' + data + '</code></pre>');

            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#ajax-form-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus=' + textStatus + ', errorThrown=' + errorThrown + '</code></pre>');
            });

        });
    }
});
```

In action, jQuery validation not work with my form. how do fix this ?

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/fcuswvf1/2/

Comment: What behavior are you expecting?  In the jsfiddle example, you only get an alert if you put data into the field and then delete it.  Does that part not work for you either?

Comment: @ClaySills: if fields is empty u see alerts but if fields not empty jquery submit form data. in ie both not work for me !!

Comment: might be helpful. go through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the click handler on the button inside the `submitHandler`. This way, when a user clicks the button, the click event doesn't fire. You can simply remove the click handling lines from the 'submitHandler`, so that the code inside is called directly whenever`submitHandler` is triggered.